# scrolling gridView is too slow

Tags: java, android, image, gridview

I have a gridView of all images from internal memory, each image is consisted of title and path of the image to build a bitmap from it.
The problem is scrolling the gridview is very slow and not smooth at all.

I need to find a way to make it easier and smoother when scrolling.
I have searched a lot for it and all I found is that the best thing is to use Glide library which I already did.
Note that grid items are 1208 item, maybe this is a large number to scroll within ?

This is how I get the images list

```
public List<Image> getImageData(){
            List<Image> imageList = new ArrayList<>();
            Uri uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE};
            cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
                while (cursor.moveToNext())
                    imageList.add(new Image(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1)));
                cursor.close();
            }
            return imageList;
        }
```

and this is how I use the adapter

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder;
            if(convertView == null){
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.images_item, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.imageView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
                viewHolder.textViewTitle = convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_title);
                viewHolder.textViewItemsCount = convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_items_count);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }
            else
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            viewHolder.textViewTitle.setText(imageList.get(position).title);
            Glide.with(context).load(decodeSampledBitmapFromPath(imageList.get(position).path, 500, 500))
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC).skipMemoryCache(false).into(viewHolder.imageView);
            return convertView;
        }

        public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromPath(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
            // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            // Calculate inSampleSize
            options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);
            // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
        }

        public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
            // Raw height and width of image
            final int height = options.outHeight;
            final int width = options.outWidth;
            int inSampleSize = 1;
            if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
                final int halfHeight = height / 2;
                final int halfWidth = width / 2;
                // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
                // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
                while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
                    inSampleSize *= 2;
                }
            }
            return inSampleSize;
        }
```

Comment: Glide is a nice choise, Picasso too. I suggest switching to a recycler view with a GridLayoutManager()

Comment: I don't think switching will make much difference to performance (although I would still agree with recommending it). The OP is using the view holder pattern correctly etc. If it's still lagging then I suspect it's all to do with the image loading.

Comment: Maybe this method is taking too long decodeSampledBitmapFromPath() why not let glide control that with .placeholder() and .centerCrop() or another transformation?

Comment: @HenryTwist i tried your solution but unfortunately no difference

Comment: @javdromero i tried your solution but unfortunately no difference